# Creating Named Ranges/Tables using cell values

Tags: excel, named-ranges

I have 300 tables of differing width (different # of columns) and equal length (2 rows). 
Next to each table is a single identifying number, say 1 to 300.

I want to know if there is any automatic way to name the "2 x #ofCols" tables using the ID next to each table without selecting the table and manually naming it. Names could be
any suitable format, but require appending the ID to a letter or name, i.e. Table1, Table2... And so on.

Or is there any other handy workaround that anyone can think of?

Comment: Yes, you could likely use VBA to loop through tables and reassign the name. What have you tried?

Comment: Honestly, I haven't tried much besides the manual method, and that is rather tedious. One thing I should probably note is that the tables aren't formatted as tables. They are essentially just 300 pairs of rows of data.